# Warum wird das Adjektiv hier nicht dekliniert?

Tags: adjective

Aus *Die Unendliche Geschicte*:

> Manche geben **all ihr** Hab und Gut hin, um im Glücksspiel zu gewinnen,
>   oder opfern alles einer fixen Idee, die niemals Wirklichkeit werden
>   kann.

Warum `all ihr` und nicht "alle ihre". Hier ist es [attributiv](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-A/Texte/Flexionskl.html#Anchor-Attributiver-47857) aber nicht aus der [Liste](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-A/Texte/A-Invar.html) der unveränderlichen Adjektiven. Ich erinnere mich vage, dass es mit Wörtern wie "mancher" und "solcher" verbunden ist, aber ich erinnere mich nicht an die Regel.

Comment: [RHA's link](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10522/how-to-know-which-form-of-all-alle-allen-aller-allem-alles-to-use?noredirect=1&lq=1) für all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Alle ihre* stimmt nur dann, wenn das Folgende im Plural geschrieben ist.
[Das Hab und Gut](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Hab_und_Gut) ist jedoch Singular, darum muss es *all ihr* sein.

> All ihr Können [Singular]
>
> Alle ihre Sachen [Plural]